# IIS multiple-IP-address server with host header conflicts with Owin Self-Host Service

Tags: ssl, owin, iis-8.5, self-hosting, hostheader

I'm trying to get my windows service working and running into a bit of a conundrum. IIS has a UCC cert installed with a host name, but I want to have my OWIN self-host windows service host share the host name.

However, if the IIS site is on and the windows service is started, the IIS site trumps the windows service and I get 404's calling the windows service's endpoints.  If I shut off the IIS site, I can then access the windows service.

If the IIS site is on and the windows service isn't started, and I try to start it, I get an Access Denied error (ostensibly because IIS has already claimed all the things with that host name (all ur endpoints r belong to us)).

So is there a way to get IIS to not immediately swallow all services for that host name?  Is there an exception or something that I can put in so https://host/api method calls won't be absorbed by IIS?

Comment: Or is there a way to get the OWIN self-host server to simply inject its endpoint?

Comment: More info; I know now that it is the Host Name setting in IIS. If I go back to the development certificate that was installed previously, the site's SSL works just fine without the Host Name setting - and the Self-Host API also works just fine. If I add the host name such that it matches the cert, the site's SSL works, but the Self-Host's API is unreachable (404's), unless the site is shut off - then the API is fully accessible until the site is turned back on.